# How do I find the euclidean distance between two lists without using numpy or zip?

Tags: python, list, euclidean-distance

​​How do I find the euclidean distance between two lists without using either the numpy or the zip feature? Furthermore, the lists are of equal length, but the length of the lists are not defined.

For example:

ex 1.

```
list_1 = [0, 5, 6]
list_2 = [1, 6, 8]
```

ex2.

```
list_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
list_2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So far I have:

```
    def euclidean_distance(p1, p2):
        sum = 0
        #(I think I need a for loop, possibly nested? --> For x in... for y in...)
        ans = (x-y) ** 2
        sum += ans
        return (sum) ** (1/2)
```

Comment: `sum` is Python builtin, try not to use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify your `euclidean_distance()` function like this:

```
def euclidean_distance(p1, p2):
        return abs(p1- p2)
```

One solution would be to just loop through the list outside of the function:

```
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    print(euclidean_distance(list_1[i], list_2[i]))
```

Another solution would be to use the map() function:

```
for result in map(euclidean_distance, list_1, list_2):
    print(result)
```

For

```
list_1 = [0, 5, 6]
list_2 = [1, 6, 8]
```

this would give you the output:

```
1
1
2
```